# Is there a phrase or slang word for a man who is always chatting women up?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, slang

He can be rich or poor, educated or not, vulgar or polite, handsome or not, but what characterizes this guy is his way with words and his garrulousness. More importante, he is notorious for making a pass at almost any woman.  Whether or not he succeeds is irrelevant.

I'm not looking for lists. Just the best slang word or phrase for this type of person.

I'm not looking for medical terms.

I'm not looking for old-usage such as "a Don Juan."

> chat up (verb) -to talk flirtatiously to (a person), esp with the intention of seducing him or her.  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/chat+up

EDIT - (context where I would use it)

- Jim has been dancing with my sister all evening.  Do you think he is a nice guy?
- Er... perhaps I shouldn't tell you this but when we were in College he was notorious for making  passes at almost any girl. As a matter of fact he was a .................

Comment: `Womanizer` comes to mind, or possibly `player`. Though both are not limited to just chatting up women, and do imply actually being successful at it as far as I understand. `Smooth talker` might work, but is not limited to romance / seduction.

Comment: Charmer. Sweet-talker. Desperate.

Comment: Why the close vote ?   Is this a duplicate? Off-topic? Am I asking for lists?  You should be transparent.

Comment: The close vote is probably because this is "primarily opinion-based"; with no example of why you want it or how you intend to use it, all we can do is put forth a bunch of ideas and let you pick one that you like best right now.  That does not fit well with the concept of "asking questions for which there is a more-or-less objectively correct answer."

Comment: With that in mind, *skirt-chaser* might also suit whatever need you're trying to fulfill.

Comment: @Hellion All I want to know is whether there is a word or phrase that fits the definition I've given and I don't think I can make it more specific. I can't help it if some people answer whatever comes first to their minds irrespective of whether it really fits the definition I've given. In my  mother tongue we have two phrases for that kind of person, both of them colloquialisms, but I couldn't find any translation for them.

Comment: @Hellion "skirt-chaser" sounds like exactly what I'm looking for. If you give it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's *skirt-chaser*, defined at [freedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/skirt+chaser) as

> a man who is aggressive in making amorous advances to women.

Some examples:

- "Robinson was supposed to have been one of the most incorrigible skirt-chasers of his time." [(oxforddictionaries.com)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/skirt-chaser)
- "Troy vows to relinquish the life of a skirt-chaser if only he can get Angel in his arms." [(oxforddictionaries.com)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/skirt-chaser)
- "Sarah couldn't seem to escape Kenny's gaze, and she thought of him as a skirt chaser." [(Urbandictionary.com)](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=skirt%20chaser)

Comment: Examples would be welcome.

Comment: If you've seen the *Star Trek* reboot movie (starring Chris Pine and Zachary Quinto), James Kirk is shown to be quite a skirt-chaser in the opening third or so of the movie, going out of his way to introduce himself to any attractive female within his line of sight.

Answer (score 2):

Consider *[hound dog](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hound_dog)*

> (slang) A promiscuous man. [*Wiktionary*]

Answer (score 1):

A **pick up artist** is someone who is intentionally and systematically approaching women with the intention of seducing them.

A term for pursues intimate relationships with a lot of women is a **womaniser** or a **casanova**.

A man who is good at chatting or flirting with woman, would be a **charmer**. This term tends to be a compliment, and charmer isn't necesserily sleeping with the women he flirts with. For example a young man might be good at talking to older woman at a cocktail party, and be known as a charmer.

A man who dates several women at once, would be a **player**. This term has connotations of dishonesty. (ie. if the women he is dating were aware that he is dating other women, it might not be so appropriate).

Answer (score 1):

The most common slang term for this act (not so much the person, but I've heard it used as a noun) is **mack**. When someone is hitting on a woman, he is **macking**. This is far and away the most common and popular way to describe hitting on a woman right now (Where I live in the US anyway, slang is very region specific).

I'm surprised it hasn't been said but **playboy** would fit depending on the success rate of your friend!

Answer (score 0):

Quite vulgar from British slang is "***[fanny rat](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fanny%20rat)***", with "fanny" being slang for vagina.

Googling the term will show a number of references on forums, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A not so long ago term which is neither overly derisive not overly admiring, but kind of dismissive, was "playboy." It was a sorta tongue-in-cheek manner of "discussing," but not a length, a person with such proclivities.

Comment: "Oh, it's okay, he can't help it. He's just a friendly playboy; no cause for concern."

Comment: On the other hand, judging by the question, I fail to see any wantonness as to expressions as lascivious as some suggestions that are offered.

Answer (score -1):

Charmer, womanizer, hustler, etc.